# not able to run isql on cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin, sybase, isql

When I am trying to run sybase query through isql syntex it is giving below error.

Error -

> "The context allocation routine failed when it tried to load
>   localization files!! One or more following problems may caused the
>   failure
>
> Your sybase home directory is C:\Sybase. Check the environment
>   variable SYBASE if it is not the one you want! Using locale name
>   "en_US.UTF-8" defined in environment variable LANG Locale name
>   "en_US.UTF-8" doesn't exist in your C:\Sybase\locales\locales.dat file
>   An error occurred when attempting to allocate localization-related
>   structures. "

I checked the environment path variable which is correct.

Comment: Does it run from `cmd.exe`? How about from a `cmd.exe` started from `cygwin`, i.e. `cygstart cmd`?

Comment: So does the locale file exist? Can you show us what your current environment (`env` command output) variables are set to (not just $SYBASE)?

Answer (score 3):

I found that if I run

```
unset LANG
```

before running isql, then isql works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If above is the output, then it means that the environmental variable is not set properly.
In order to set the environment variable - go to sybase directory

```
$ cd sybase/
```

and set environment variable

```
$ **export LANG=en_IN.UTF-8**
```

And then start the server.

```
$ cd sybase/
```

Now go to **OCS-16_0** folder

```
$ cd OCS-16_0/
```

And then connect to the server.

```
$ bin/isql64 -Usa -SSYBASEASE
```

where

- sa is my user
- SYBASEASE is my Sybase server name

It will ask for password. enter it, and it will connect to the sql shell.

Comment: Thanks all for your response.