# Executing iqisql using JSch fails with "An error occurred when attempting to allocate localization-related structures"

Tags: java, sybase, jsch, remotecommand

I have a requirement to run a script on remote machine for this I am using Jsch
I cannot store the script in remote machine.
below is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
/eniq/sybase_iq/OCS-15_0/bin/iqisql -Uce -Pce -Sendb -b -n <<EOF!

SELECT SUM(COUNTERS) FROM ADAPTER WHERE STARTTIME = "Aug  8 2016 11:30:00.000000PM"

go
exit
EOF!
```

if I run the script in Linux machine I am able to get the required outut

```
#: /eniq/sybase_iq/OCS-15_0/bin/iqisql -Uce -Pce -Sendb -b -n <<EOF!
> SELECT SUM(COUNTERS) FROM ADAPTER WHERE STARTTIME = "Aug  8 2016 11:30:00.000000PM"
> go
> exit
> EOF!
                                   168002

 (1 row affected)
```

But when I am trying to run the script using below java code -

package org.rhq.plugin.eniq;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

 import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
 import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
 import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
 import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

 public class JSchTest {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(JSchTest.class);

    public void executeCommand() {
        try {
            String command = "/eniq/sybase_iq/OCS-15_0/bin/iqisql -Uce -Pce -Sendb -b -n <<EOF!" + "\n"
                    + "SELECT SUM(COUNTERS) FROM ADAPTER WHERE STARTTIME = \"Aug  8 2016 11:30:00.000000PM\""
                    + "\n" +

                    "go" + "\n" + "exit" + "\n" + "EOF!";
            String host = "107.250.237.13";
            String user = "dcuser";
            String password = "dcuser";

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            ;
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();

            log.error("Channel Connected to machine " + host + " server with command: " + command);

            try {
                InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
                String line = null;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.error("Eniq DB Output line is " + line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run this I get the below error as outut-  An error occurred when attempting to allocate localization-related structures

is something to do with locale name "en_US.UTF-8" ? how to set in jsch

N.B: I cannot use sybase drivers in connection because of requirement dont permit

Answer (score 0):

According to this previous StackOverflow answer

[not able to run isql on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235042/not-able-to-run-isql-on-cygwin)

you should do

```
unset LANG
```

before running `isql`. So maybe same is true before running `iqisql`.

Comment: How to do it using jsch

Comment: String command = "unset LANG; /eniq/sybase_iq/OCS-15_0/bin/iqisql -Uusername -Ppassword -Sdb -b -n <<EOF!" + "\n" + "SELECT SUM(Employee.Names) FROM DC.EMPLOYEES WHERE JOININGDATE = \"Aug 8 2016 11:30:00.000000PM\"" + "\n" + "go" + "\n" + "exit" + "\n" + "EOF!"; I tried modifying this way but no help same error